# Can I clear out broken/uninstalled apps that still show up in the app list?

Tags: applications, link2sd

I had some apps stored on my SD card that I have since wiped. The apps still show up in my app list in `Settings`->`Manage applications`. How do I refresh this list?

Rebooting the phone doesn't help, and clicking on one of the entries causes the Settings app to crash. I even tried wiping the Dalvik Cache, but the missing apps are still listed.

One special thing to note is that I had used [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) to link the apps onto a second partition on the SD card. This is different from the built-in Android method of moving to the sd card. Link2SD creates symlinks so that any app can be moved, and the SD card can be mounted on a computer without temporarily disabling the app (because they are on a second, unmounted partition). I don't know if using Link2SD changes my situation.

Note that these uninstalled apps do *not* show up in another application's app list, such as Titanium Backup.

[image: Pointers to missing/uninstalled apps]

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue.

I found that if I use link2sd to uninstall the app, it should remove the entry from the app manager.

Answer (score 1):

Not having used *Link2SD* I cannot tell for sure -- but being familiar with the principle, there's one thing that should work with a rooted device:

1. make sure you had removed the files on the Link2SD partition
2. using a (root) file explorer, navigate to `/data/data` and check for symlinks showing the same package names listed in your screenshot. Delete them.

This might still leave "traces" in some system configuration files (for sure this is valid for the `packages.xml` which stores the apps' permissions). [SD Maid - System cleaning tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) should be able to clean up most of the remains.

Still, this manual approach is not 100% "clean". Another option might involve re-installing *Link2SD* and see whether you can cleanly remove the apps with it (or even re-installing the apps, moving them again with *Link2SD* in case this didn't happen automatically due to the symlinks, and then removing them again).

If all else fails, one ugly but very clean solution remains: a *factory reset*. Don't forget to backup everything before this -- you've got *Titanium Backup* to take care for this step, as your question states.

Comment: Titanium backup will also backup the symlinks :(

Comment: @LiamW You got something wrong: Those apps the OP wanted to get rid of either. I was talking about backing up *remaining* apps and their data, not the symlinked ones which are either NIL'd.

Comment: Titanium will backup thy symlinks, which are causing the erroneous app entries in settings. Those erroneous entries are because the app data still exists in `/data/data`

Comment: Again, @LiamW: It won't backup those unless you select them. So thanks for the hint (surely something the OP should keep in mind and take care for exclusion).